# Compile java source with unmappable character using IBM JDK

Tags: java

I have a project, which has many java source files.

All java source files will be treated as UTF-8 encoded, but some of them contains unmappable UTF-8 character in comments, these files are commited by some members in our team, and they use GBK encoding for their local project.

I want compile it with ant on a AIX system, which has IBM JDK installed

But the compile task fails, as javac throws errors like this:

```
xx/xx/XX.java unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

Any easy solution ?

---

**Edit**:
As I know why the error happen, and I know how to fix encoding problem for a single java source file, My problem is actually how to identify those files have encoding problem while there is too many source files.

Comment: Tell them not to do that? Seriously, get everyone to use the same character encoding - anything else will lead to madness. Pretty much *everything* supports UTF-8 these days, so why not just standardize on that?

Comment: Depending on your source control, I suggest adding a hook and stopping this from happening.

Comment: [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html) takes an _encoding_ switch. However, you may still have issues if other files have been committed with other encodings. I agree with others that the project should mandate (and enforce where possible) a single encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are steps how I fixed my problem:

As only part of source files contains unmappable UTF-8 characters, so we can find all such Java files by increasing the number of `javac` max errors by specifying a compiler argument when compiling with ant:

```
<compilearg line="-Xmaxerrs 100000" />
```

And dump error messages to a file when you call `ant` command.

```
ant -buildfile=compile.xml > error.txt
```

Then you can use Notepad++ to do some trick job on the output file to get the list of file which has encoding problem then you can fix them.

1. Use regular expression to remove unneeded content; and
2. Use TextFX to sort and remove duplicate lines.